# Does ngModelController.$setViewValue needs to wrapped with scope.apply on 1.3.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I had a little experiment with writing a custom form directive.
Based on the example for custom form directive in the [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) I tried to make a point that you have to wrap your `$setViewValue` call with `scope.$apply` and show how the model is not updating without it. But to my surprise I removed the `scope.$apply` wrapping and the code still works. 
So I did some digging in angular source code and found out that with changes made to support 1.3 ngModelOptions `$setViewValue` already calls `scope.$apply` and now actually wrapping it causes an **extra unnecessary digest cycle**.
Here's the implementation from angular 1.3.15 source:

```
this.$setViewValue = function(value, trigger) {
 ctrl.$viewValue = value;
 if (!ctrl.$options || ctrl.$options.updateOnDefault) {
  ctrl.$$debounceViewValueCommit(trigger);
 }
};

this.$$debounceViewValueCommit = function(trigger) {
var debounceDelay = 0,
    options = ctrl.$options,
    debounce;

if (options && isDefined(options.debounce)) {
  debounce = options.debounce;
  if (isNumber(debounce)) {
    debounceDelay = debounce;
  } else if (isNumber(debounce[trigger])) {
    debounceDelay = debounce[trigger];
  } else if (isNumber(debounce['default'])) {
    debounceDelay = debounce['default'];
  }
}

$timeout.cancel(pendingDebounce);
if (debounceDelay) {
  pendingDebounce = $timeout(function() {
    ctrl.$commitViewValue();
  }, debounceDelay);
} else if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
  ctrl.$commitViewValue();
} else {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    ctrl.$commitViewValue();
  });
}
```

};

and here's angular's [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1p32AaKzDxfgSNQysQQ?p=preview) without the `scope.$apply` wrapper.

So am I missing something or do angular need to update their docs? 
Can anyone think of a reason to wrap with `scope.$apply` in this case?

Comment: I don't see in official docs where is mentioned to wrap it inside $apply?

Comment: the example is wrapping... http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't missing anything, as of 1.3 there is no need to call scope.$apply. I actually made a pull request to fix this example and it was accepted and merged.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of form validator using the ngModellController 
and doesn't use $scope.$apply

```
(function(angular)
{
    var directive = function()
    {
        return  {`enter code here`
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
                //  controller.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
                //     if (moment( viewValue).isValid()) {
                console.log($scope);
                controller.$validators.formDateValidator =
                    function(modelValue, viewValue)
                {
                    return moment( viewValue).isValid();
                };
                //    return viewValue;
                //} else {
                //    controller.$setValidity('form-date-validator', false);
                //    return undefined;
                //}
            }
        };

    }
    angular.module('ToDoListApp').
        directive('formDateValidator',
        [directive]);
}(window.angular));
```

Comment: Yes, But validation have no reason for calling $apply cause it's not suppose to update the model anyway. you set the validity and let angular do all the work

Comment: The form validation do update the model because the model won't be updated unless validation process has succeeded validating the data. 
However, the commented code above (the parser sections) is from angular ver-1.2 and the uncommented code (the $validator) is from angular 1.3


In both cases you won't see any $scope.$apply, I think the reason they use the $scope.$apply on your example above, is because the use of $timeout and the fact that you cannot be sure whether your model update will cause an apply-digest cycle or not.